# Return the depth of a specific node with value binary search tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

My problem is asking me to return the depth of the node with `value` in the tree.

For example, if I did `depth(root, 7, 0 [depth initially])`, it should return 2.

[image]

My first try, I did something like this

```
# value is the value wanted, count measures the 'depth'

def depth(root, value, count):

    # if we are not at a empty node
    if root != None:
        # if we found our data, then just return the count (depth)
        if root.data == value:
            return count


        # otherwise increase count, and traverse both sides
        else:
            count += 1
            count = depth(root.left, value, count)
            count = depth(root.right, value, count)


    return count
```

When I run this though I get depth = 6, and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning when you should, in the second part of your branch.

Suppose that you do not find the target value in `root`. Then you set count to the result of searching left. Then you set count to the result of searching left (again).

You never search right, and you return count whether you found the target or not (after falling out of the if).

A better approach would be to:

```
if you match the target:
    return count
else:
    search on the left side.
    if that is not None, return it.
    search on the right side.
    regardless of whether it's None or not, return it.
```

Now your return value will either be `None`, meaning "couldn't find the target", or `count` when the target was found.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake on my behalf, I meant to switch to right but looks like I copied the code wrong. I edited it

Answer (score 0):

Why `count` on the way down when you can `count` on the way back up:

```
def depth(root, value):
    # if we are at a empty node return infinity
    if not root:
        return float('inf')

    # if we found our data, then just return 0
    if root.data == value:
        return 0
    # otherwise traverse both sides
    return 1 + min(depth(root.left, value), depth(root.right, value))
```

To get rid of `min()` then you can `return None` as your terminal case and then implement checks, but it is ugly and not idiomatic:

```
def depth(root, value):
    # if we are at a empty node return None
    if not root:
        return None

    # if we found our data, then just return 0
    if root.data == value:
        return 0

    # otherwise, traverse both sides
    c = depth(root.left, value)
    if c is None:
        c = depth(root.right, value)
        if c is None:
            return None
    return c + 1
```

Alternatively implement it as a `BFS`:

```
def depth(root, value):
    q = [(root, 0)]
    while q:
        node, depth = q.pop(0)
        if node.data == value:
            return depth
        depth += 1
        if node.left:
            q.append((node.left, depth))
        if node.right:
            q.append((node.right, depth))
    return None
```

Comment: What is the min for? Whichever path was closer?

Comment: How could I get rid of that min? Assuming the tree has unique values

Comment: What do you return down the paths that do not have the value, you can implement checks or simply use `min()`? An alternative is to do a Breadth-First-Search using a queue.